# Understanding the syntax of connect() function in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have seen that in order to connect a child component inside `<Provider>` to the redux store, we use `connect()` function. It is usually written as:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {name: state}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Name) //'Name' is the component's name.
```

But I am failing to understand the syntax here. Here `mapStateToProps()` requires a state argument. But When we pass `mapStateToProps` to the `connect()` function, we are not passing any state to it. Also what is the use of `(Name)` just after `connect()`? How is this syntactically correct?

Comment: How is it _not_ syntactically correct? You should learn JavaScript before you learn complicated frameworks because you seem to be missing the forest for the trees

Comment: javascript clousers .. it will help you to understand the syntax of connect()  https://hackernoon.com/how-to-redux-with-react-836ed6d85330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simplified answer would be this:
when you pass the `mapStateToProps` function to `connect`, somewhere in the `connect` method its calling the `mapStateToProps` that you passed to it and its giving it the `state` so you don't have to worry about it.

the second part is the weird sytax, basically the `connect` function returns another function that you invoke and pass it the component in this case `Name`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as the "weird" looking syntax goes, just imagine a function that returns another function:

```
function add(x) {
    return function (y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}
```

Here if you call the add function and pass the `x` argument it'll return the inner function:

```
let inner = add(10);
```

And now you can call the inner function itself and pass the `y` argument

```
let result = inner(11);
```

And `result` is going to be equal to 21.

The shorter way to write it is to just chain the two calls together:

```
let result = add(10)(11);
```

Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Great answer. You could add that this is called a closure in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 1):

Connect returns a Higher Order Component, which is basically a component wrapped with some extra functionality.  When you create the HOC, you first create the wrapper (using whatever logic you wish to share among components) which then takes a new argument (the Component name you are wrapping).  So think of it like this:

`const wrapper = connect(mapStateToProps);
 const HOC = wrapper(Name);`

Connect also takes care of passing the redux store to `mapStateToProps` as the state argument. If you do not want your component to listen to the store, but want it connected for some other reused logic that you have, you can call `connect()(Name)`, leaving the argument for mapStateToProps `undefined`. It wouldn't make sense for you to pass this local state into there because you already have access to the local state.